# Estimation of cell count of E.coli culture

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

Can I get some help with an estimation of a cell count in a culture of E.coli cells if we assume we begin with $10^6$ cells, that they divide every 30 minutes and they are incubated for 12 hours?

I do not know how to do the calculation with a start number that is not 2, if it was it would just be $2^{24}$. But how is it done when the starting number of cells is $10^6$?

Is it $(10^6)^{24}$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You start with $10^6$ cells. After 30 min they double, so there are $2⋅10^6$ cells. After another 30 minutes they double again, so there are $2⋅2⋅10^6$ or $2^2⋅10^6$ cells. After three doubling periods, the number of cells is $2^3⋅10^6$. Doing this, the [equation for exponential growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Basic_formula) should become evident. All you must do now is determine the number of doubling periods in 12 hours.